# PHP search array using wildcard?

Tags: php, arrays, search

Assume that i have the following arrays containing:

```
Array (
     [0] => 099/3274-6974
     [1] => 099/12-365898
     [2] => 001/323-9139
     [3] => 002/3274-6974
     [4] => 000/3623-8888
     [5] => 001/323-9139
     [6] => www.somesite.com
)
```

Where:

- Values that starts with `000/, 002/ and 001/` represents mobile (cell) phone numbers
- Values that starts with `099/` represents telephone (fixed) numbers
- Vales that starts with `www.` represents web sites

I need to convert given array into 3 new arrays, each containing proper information, like arrayTelephone, arrayMobile, arraySite.

Function in_array works only if i know whole value of key in the given array, which is not my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through all the items and sort them into the appropriate arrays based on the first 4 characters.

```
$arrayTelephone = array();
$arrayMobile = array();
$arraySite = array();

foreach($data as $item) {
    switch(substr($item, 0, 4)) {
        case '000/':
        case '001/':
        case '002/':
            $arrayMobile[] = $item;
            break;
        case '099/':
            $arrayTelephone[] = $item;
            break;
        case 'www.':
            $arraySite[] = $item;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: Code examples with a description are actually excellent for learning. I suppose you have the right to vote whatever you want, though.

Answer (score 2):

Create the three empty arrays, loop through the source array with `foreach`, inspect each value (regexp is nice for this) and add the items to their respective arrays.

Comment: Please don't recommend regular expressions for this, give the guy a chance to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the array and push the value to the correct new array based on your criteria. Example:

```
<?php

$fixed_array = array();

foreach ($data_array as $data) {
    if (strpos($data, '099') === 0) {
        $fixed_array[] = $data;
    }

    if ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes i actually wrote the full code with preg_match but after reading some comments i accept that its better to show the way.

You will create three different arrays named arrayTelephone, arrayMobile, arraySite.

than you will search though your first array with foreach or for loop. Compare your current loop value with your criteria and push the value to one of the convenient new arrays (arrayTelephone, arrayMobile, arraySite) after pushing just continue your loop with "continue" statement.

You can find the solution by looking add the  [Perfect PHP Guide](http://php.net/docs.php)